# Font pixellation with properly licensed and declared web fonts

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have the following [page](http://184.106.89.208/government/) loaded in a test environment.

To start, the fonts are properly licensed and have been downloaded from myfonts.com and declared as follows:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLT';src: url('css/webfonts/3019F7_2_0.eot');src: url('css/webfonts/3019F7_2_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_2_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_2_0.woff') format('woff'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_2_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLT-Bold';src: url('css/webfonts/3019F7_1_0.eot');src: url('css/webfonts/3019F7_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_1_0.woff') format('woff'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
@font-face {font-family: 'HelveticaNeueLT-Light';src: url('css/webfonts/3019F7_3_0.eot');src: url('css/webfonts/3019F7_3_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_3_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_3_0.woff') format('woff'),url('css/webfonts/3019F7_3_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

If you look at the page in Chrome for PC (v47), you will see that the text is highly pixellated, most evident in the [Contact Us button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5fqG.jpg). In Chrome for Mac, the button is crystal clear. As a rough estimate, this is 30% because the Chrome for Mac rendering engine rendered the page more clearly and 70% because I added the following code to the CSS rule for the button:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
```

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what is going on here? You can check out the [stylesheet](http://184.106.89.208/wp-content/themes/blueprint2016/style.css?ver=4.4) to see if anything there helps troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Maybe this topic can help you out, especially the second answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272073/why-are-my-google-web-fonts-pixelated

Comment: @StefanNeuenschwander I checked the link and implemented the solution suggested in the second answer. Unfortunately, it did not solve the problem as I am still seeing the same levels of pixellation. I am a novice developer so if you could check my stylesheet to see if the suggested fix was properly implemented, that would be great.

Comment: tip from 2016: stop using all the unnecessary formats, they've not been needed for a few years now; everything supports WOFF. You can ditch EOT because Microsoft has abandoned all the IE versions that don't do WOFF, you can ditch SVG because it was abandoned as a font format by *everyone* years ago, you can ditch the TTF/OTF originals because WOFF is a byte-for-byte wrapper of them (but with lossless compression). So: just use WOFF, simplify your life. And your site payload. It also means only one source of rendering quirks to debug.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated the CSS to use WOFF2 and WOFF only but the problem remains. I'm pretty sure there is a bug in Chrome that specifically relates to Helvetica Neue. I can find the odd post through Google where people bring up the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not and expert but fiddling with inspector I notice two things

1. http://184.106.89.208/wp-content/themes/blueprint2016/font/stylesheet.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2. You are forcing 16px on the font and somehow that is pretty bad on your font. If I remove the 16px from .live_more_btn a then it [looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoPpd.jpg) acceptable.

Comment: Your second point appears to be the solution to the problem. Thanks!